# Connect an array to a signal slot mechanism in Qt

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, signals-slots

I created a `QSlider *x_slider[8]` array and now I want to create a connect to a slot like this,

```
connect(x_slider[0], SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(slider_x(int)));
```

but as I don't want to create a slot to every slider in the `x_slider` array the `int` received in `slider_x` slot should be in this case a 0.

How can I do that?, in the code I present it receives the `int` from `ValueChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `QSignalMapper`:

```
auto sigMap = new QSignalMapper( this );
for ( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i ) {
    x_slider[i] = new QSlider( this );
    connect( x_slider[i], SIGNAL( valueChanged( int ) ),
             sigMap, SLOT( map() ) );

    sigMap->setMapping( x_slider[i], i );
}
connect( sigMap, SIGNAL( mapped( int ) ),
         this, SLOT( slider_x( int ) ) );

void MyClass::slider_x( int i )
{
    int value = x_slider[i]->value();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @SamuelNLP I don't know why your edit suggestion was rejected, it was clearly correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect every QSlider from yours array, and then in your slot `slider_x` you can find out, what slider sent signal via `sender()` function. http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2/qt4/qobject.html#sender

Just loop through your array, and pointer to object, returned by sender() equals to QSlider in an array will mean, that you found your indice of an array.